# Console crashes outputting pointer array and iterations C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am busy working on a simple concept to display pointer arrays and iterations of a for loop in C++

My compiler is not giving much away and when I run the program the console is saying the following and returning 3 "The application has requested the Runtime to terminate in an unusual way.

The crash occurs on this line:

```
      cout << i + 1 << " " << *(pArray + i) << endl;
```

but when I run this program ommiting either i + 1 or *(pArray + i) it runs without errors or crashing.

Is it illegal to try and output as I am trying to do above?

See below for the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int * pArray;
int SIZE;
int module;
pArray = new int[SIZE];  

cout <<"Enter the number of Assignments ";
cin >> SIZE;

cout <<"input assignment number " ;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)    
   {    
        cin >> module;    
        *(pArray + i) = module;

   }
   // Print array
   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
  cout << i + 1 << " " << *(pArray + i) << endl;
   }
   cout << endl;

   delete[] pArray;  // Deallocate array via delete[] operator

   return 0;
}
```

I am admittedly a little nervous to ask this question but I just need someone to explain why this is happening as I am battling to find any reference on this type of situation.

Thanks

Comment: It could be an idea to assign some value to `SIZE`, before using it.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Thanks, I'll do this. Appreciate feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You use `SIZE` two lines before you initialize it.

Move

```
pArray = new int[SIZE];
```

to after where you obtain the value of `SIZE`.

(Also: this would be so much easier with `std::vector`.)

Comment: Thank you! I feel intensely dim. I feel despondent each time I ask a question on this forum as I am continuously marked down. I am very new C++ and occasionally as a student studying long distance I feel overwhelmed with these concepts and just appreciate a bit of interaction. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int * pArray;
int SIZE;
int module;
pArray = new int[SIZE];
```

SIZE is not initialised yet, so, it would be some junk value.
Initialise it before using it.

You could also Check for success/failure of new.

```
pArray = new(nothrow) int[SIZE];

if(pArray)
//logic
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. This makes sense. Not sure how I missed that.

Comment: It's very unlkely that `new` would fail here; and if it did the resulting exception would seem to be a perfectly good way to expose that.

Comment: @AlanStokes So then are you are saying that if I build an exception handler like above it would catch this is size hadn't been initialized?

Comment: No. I'm saying that @basav's second suggestion wouldn't improve things. If the `new` fails you will find out about it anyway. (It might fail given uninitialised input, but it might not.)

Comment: @Alan: agreed .in normal circumstances, not needed.i come from an embedded background and again, it really depends on the use case